Can Player 1 get 100 X’s in a row?
Two players take turns playing a game.  Before the game starts there is a sheet of graph paper with a square grid (extending indefinitely in all directions) with no marks on it other than the squares of the grid (represented below).

Player 1 (who starts the game), when it is their turn, can put an X into any two empty squares of the graph paper. Player 2, when it is their move, can put an O into any empty square. Is it always possible for Player 1 to get 100 X’s in a row (vertically or horizontally) no matter how Player 2 plays?
Attribution:  Mathematical Circles (Russian Experience)

This looks very familiar (including the solution posted by Matsmath), are you sure this isn't a dulicate that was asked here before?

I assume Player 2 is attempting to prevent player 1 putting 100 Xs in a row, and the question is really "is it always possible for player 1 to get 100 Xs in a row?". Otherwise it's quite obviously yes (Player 1 puts all their Xs next to each other in the middle row; player 2 puts all their Os on a different row).

@quarague I agree that my question is very similar.  I was not aware of the question https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/tic-tac-toe-1000-in-a-row when I posted my question.

@psmears You raise a good point.  I have updated the question.


 Yes. I will explain how to get N=3 marks consecutively, and then filling out the gaps is left as an exercise. We will put all the X marks in a single row. Let's identify this row with the integer numbers. In the first phase of the game, Player 1 will put his marks to integers which are a multiple of 100. There are always a choice like this, irrespective of the position of Os. After doing this let's say 900 times, there will be 1800 X marks far away form each other, and only at most half of them will have an O mark ``nearby''. So, after this phase, there are 900 locations on the board, far away from each other, where there is an X at position 100k, and no O marks nearby. This is the key. After finitely many steps, we have arrived to a state, where the completely empty board is replaced by a large number of areas far away from each other where there is a single X mark. Clearly, this is an improvement, and repeating this once again a finitely many times will make Player 1 win.


 During the second phase of the game Player 1 will put his marks to integers which are of the form 100k+1, next to an already positioned X from phase 1. There are at least 900 such locations. After repeating this 300 times, there will be at least 300 double X marks next to each other (as at most 300 locations can be blocked by an O mark).


 During the third phase, Player 1 wins by putting an X mark next to any of the 300 double X marks from phase 2, and wins the game.


 The same strategy can be applied for any N, although I don't immediately see the required moves to win.


+1 This is a good start.

This strategy will take a long time ($2^{99}$ moves in the first phase, $2^{98}$ in the second, etc) but it works perfectly.

If player 2 also constrains their pieces to the same row, during phase 2, player 2 can just cap off the remaining end of every row that player 1 formed. That is, [O,X,X,O]. I might be misunderstanding something.

@matt_rule O can place only one piece for X's two. In phase 1, X tries to create $2^{99}$ one-in-a-row lines, of which O can block at most half, leaving $2^{98}$ one-in-a-row lines. In phase 2, X tries to extends those to two-in-a-row lines during which O can block at most half, leaving at least $2^{97}$ two-in-a-row lines. In phase 3 X tries to extend those to three-in-a-row lines, and again O can block at most half, leaving $2^{96}$ three-in-a-row lines. etc. Phase 99 leaves at least $2^0=1$ ninetynine-in-a-row line, which X can then complete in phase 100.

@JaapScherphuis ah that makes sense, I didn't read the OP properly, next time I will!

@JaapScherphuis: I suppose this can be optimised slightly: in phase 1, player 1 only has to create $2^{98}$ one-in-a-row lines - that way at the end of phase 98 they have one 98-in-a-row line, and can bump it up to 100 straight away...
